# How to find all installed php on Linux system?

Tags: php

How to find all php (cli, php-fpm, apache-module) installed on Linux system and check which ini use each one?

Answer (score 0):

```
bool phpinfo ([ int $what = INFO_ALL ] )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Also

```
which php
```

Or

```
find / -name php 2>/dev/null
```